# Want to be able to push Ubuntu client image remotely from Ubuntu server

Tags: software-installation

I am creating a computer lab running Ubuntu Server.

I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Push the Ubuntu client image remotely from the server
2. Push open office remotely to client machine

Question - How do I accomplish this, is there a third party software?

Comment: Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask What have you tried so far? What were your results?

Comment: (1) can be done using a provisioning tool like Foreman or Fog. (2) can be done using Puppet, Ansible, Chef, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do (1) using MAAS and (2) using Landscape.

This is probably the best way on Ubuntu, but you can also use Chef, Puppet, Cobbler, and a lot of other tools.